# Updating a foreign key field for all records to reflect new primary key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, auto-increment

```
            idcustomers,firstname,lastname,address1,address2,city,state,zip,phone,email,cell,company,newid
            307,Annaa,Mondet,"705 Congressional Rd.",,"Simi Valley",CA,93065,"(805) 300-3188",,,,1
            308,Gayla,Lindquist,"2752 Sapra st",,"Thousand Oaks",CA,91360,"(805) 750-8429",,,,2
            309,Suzie,Dotan,"4568 Winnetka Ave.",,"Woodland Hills",CA,91364,"(818) 346-1732",,,,3
            310,Katie,Mulloy,"4024 Revello Pl.",,Moorpark,CA,93021,"(805) 390-7440",,,,4
            311,,,"2935 Shadowbrook ave",,Westlake,CA,91361,,,,NULL,5
            312,"Steve &amp; Kimber",Foy,"2874 Chippewaare Ave",,"Simi Valley",CA,93063,"(805) 582-0851",,"(818) 292-4550",,6
            313,Robert,Clarke,"17433 Smoke tree",,"Santa Clarita",CA,91387,"(661) 373-8922",,,,7
            314,Brett,Bucciocco,"5266 Via Capote",,"Newbury Park",CA,91320,"(818) 599-8809",,,,8
            315,Allan,Ray,"784 Holbertson Ct.",,"Simi Valley",CA,93065,"(805) 522-1412",area1@sbcgobal.net,,,9
            316,John,Zahedi,"5122 Mammoth Ave.",,"Sherman Oaks",CA,91423,"(818) 501-5344",,,,10
            317,Carmin,Appice,"26848 Marina Point Ct.",,Valencia,CA,91355,"(661) 367-4442",powerrock@sbc.gobal,"(661) 618-6201 Son cell",,11
            318,Sam,han,"7433 Shadyglade Ave #3",,"North Hollywood",CA,91605,"(213) 700-9978",hanandkoo@yahoo.com,,,12
            319,Rose,Lane,"6459 Deerbrook Cir.",,"Oak Park",CA,91377,"(818) 624-7673",,,,13
            320,Eric,Scott,"3190 Dalhart Ave",,"Simi Valley",CA,93063,"(805) 501-0185",,,,14
            321,Donna,Vella,"13021 E. Cloverdale",,Moorpark,CA,93021,,DV4Re.Aol,,NULL,15


            idevents,title,start,end,allday,url,customerid,memo,dispatchstatus
            13,"AA Meeting","2013-09-30 00:00:00","2013-09-30 00:01:00",false,,336,"AA Meeting",scheduled
            14,"AA Meeting","2013-09-30 00:00:00","2013-09-30 00:01:00",false,NULL,307,"AA Meeting",scheduled
            15,"AA Meeting","2013-09-30 00:00:00","2013-09-30 00:01:00",false,NULL,308,"AA Meeting",scheduled
```

I have created a new primary key in customers called newid. The field idcustomers of events reflects the idcustomers field in customers. I want the idcustomers field of events to now be changed to the new value located in newid. I started a query but it is not working yet...

update events set events.customerid = customers.newid where events.customerid = customers.customerid;

Can this be accomplished with an update?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can newid have the same value of an existing customer id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  events INNER JOIN customers
  ON events.customerid=customers.idcustomers
SET
  events.customerid = customers.newid
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de5e52/1)

Answer (score 2):

If you have actually defined a foreign key to MySql, then you have a problem with your update because the events.customerid references customers.idcustomers not customers.newid. Your referential integrity checks will cause the update to fail if the value in customers.newid doesn't already exist in customers.idcustomers somewhere.

Assuming this is a one-time update, you would need to:

- Drop the foreign key index between events.customerid and customers.customerid.
- Perform your update on events setting events.customerid = customers.newid
- Perform your update on customers setting customers.customerid = customers.newid. Note that this will be a problem if any of the customers.newid already exist in customers.customerid
- Recreate your foreign key index

An alternative would be to:

- Create a new customers table setting customers.customerid = customers.newid
- Drop the foreign key index between events.customerid and customers.customerid.
- Perform your update on events setting events.customerid = customers.newid
- Replace your original customers table with your new one
- Recreate your foreign key index